# Can't add element in array with powershell function

Tags: function, powershell, scripting, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have a strange problem, i have a very simple function.

This is my powershell code

```
$exclude = @()

function GetOracleDb {
param([string]$servername)
$exclude += $servername
}

GetOracleDb "Myserver2"

$exclude
```

Why my $exclude array is empty?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change it like this:

```
$global:exclude += $servername
```

The scope of $exclude inside a function is different from this one outside.

Comment: Legit for PowerShell 2.0 as well.